# Can I access VHDL record outputs from a Verilog module?

Tags: vhdl, verilog, records

I have a top level Verilog module that instantiates a VHDL block with a few outputs that are records.

Is there a good way to access these records from my Verilog top, or am I better off just breaking the records apart?

Comment: From what I've read your best option is to create a VHDL wrapper around the VHDL block and break out the record types like you mentioned.

Comment: Ahh good thinking. My original thought was to redefine the ports but a simple wrapper is a lot cleaner and easier, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can (with caveats). Create a "struct" of the same type as the "record". These two will map 1:1 as long as you do not reorder the connections. Caveat being if your tool actually supports it.

Comment: Tried in Modelsim, cannot get it to work.  I had to use a VHDL wrapper.